# How to create a subfolder using sharepoint Client Object Model

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

How to create a subfolder using Client Object Model.
I know how to create a folder under a document library but i dont know how to create a folder under a folder or a listItem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the FolderUrl property of the ListItemCreationInformation to the parent folder.

Comment: I also want to know how to. I added the FolderUrl property, but I got this error:

Invalid file name.
The file name you specified could not be used.  It may be the name of an existing file or directory, or you may not have permission to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

`FolderUrl` property of the `ListItemCreationInformation` must be set `folder.ServerRelativeUrl`. Many other advises on this situation omit mentioning this essential requirement. I was confused, which URL to pass and lost a lot of time fighting with errors when passing absolute URL or other variants.